Using Convolution Theorem to recover signal numerically from FFTs
I only somewhat understand how the Convolution Theorem works, at least for analytical functions.  I'm trying to better understand how it works when performing numerical operations on data.
I have a convolved (measured) signal, and I have the kernel which performs the act of convolution as a set of data points in the time domain.  I am trying to deconvolve the the kernel and measured signal into the original signal.  I understand that
$\mathcal F[f(t)*g(t)] = \mathcal F[f(t)]\mathcal F[g(t)]$
Where $f(t)$ is the original signal and  $g(t)$ is the kernel, respectively, $\mathcal F$ is the Fourier transform, and $*$ is the convolution operator.  Therefore
$\mathcal F[f(t)*g(t)]$ represents the measured signal, and in order to recover $f(t)$ I'd need to divide
$\frac{\mathcal F[f(t)*g(t)]}{\mathcal F[g(t)]}  = \mathcal F[f(t)]$
I can take the FFT of both the measured signal and the kernel, but what is it exactly that I am dividing?  The FFT provides several outputs as a function of frequency:
-Complex
-Real
-Imaginary
-Amplitude
-Phase
-Power
-Magnitude
-Amplitude
-dB
-Normalized dB
-RMS Amplitude
-Square Amplitude
-Square Magnitude
Which of the many FFT outputs for the measured signal and kernel are divided by each other?

This seems to be a question on Origin, not a math question

@Stelios  This question is about performing Convolution Theorem numerically, which could be done in a variety of programs.  I happen to be using Origin, but this question would be valid for any numerical method.

It’s probably element-wise division by the Complex output

This question reminds me a bit of another fairly recent question Avoiding division by zero in deconvolution.

The FFT does not provide all of those outputs. Rather, for an input signal/sequence/vector/whatever-you-want-to-call-it $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^N$, the FFT provides the discrete Fourier transform $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^N$. Now, there are many ways in which you can visualize and/or analyze $\mathbf{X}$ (e.g., plot the phase in one figure and the amplitude in another, or plot the real component in a one figure and the imaginary in another), but that doesn't change what $\mathbf{X}$ is, namely, it is a length-$N$ vector/signal/sequence of complex values.
As to your desired application, you will want to zeropad the kernel to the same size as the measured signal, take the FFT of both, and do an element-wise division using the FFT of the kernel as the denominator. You then take the inverse FFT of the result.
Be forewarned though that this approach is fraught with issues. For example, what if one of the samples of the kernel's FFT is at or near zero? If this is actual data you are working with, then you also see an amplification of the noise power, which in some cases can render the after worse than the before.
Rather than deconvolving through spectral division, a least-squares approach if often preferred. Convolution is a linear operator and as such can be represented as a matrix-vector product. If we let $\mathbf{G}$ represent convolution with the kernel $\mathbf{g}$, $\mathbf{y}$ be the observed (i.e., measured) signal, and $\mathbf{n}$ be the noise component, then we can estimate the unknown signal $\mathbf{f}$ by solving
$$
\mathbf{G} \mathbf{f} + \mathbf{n} = \mathbf{y}.
$$
This is an over-determined system whose solution is well-known. If your data are small enough, you can form the matrix $\mathbf{G}$ explicitly and use the pseudo-inverse formula directly. If your data set is large, then an LSQR-type solver can be used.
